# Conduct linear model in R on each row with a group and a subset of dates

Tags: r, performance, subset, linear-regression, nested-loops

This is building off of a previous question that I had asked ([link](https://stackoverflow.com)). I have a long nested loop and am trying to make it more efficient, ideally in dplyr. I'm pretty new to using larger datasets and am trying to improve my coding.

For each row, I have a common operation where I:

1. Count how many rows from that group are within a certain timeframe of the row I'm focusing on,
2. If there are enough rows in that timeframe and period (let's say 3), then running a linear model,
3. Saving the slope and the p-value, and
4. Using the p-value and slope to classify as an increasing trend, a decreasing trend, or as no clear trend (which I know can be done using case_when().

While the answer to my other question (linked above) helped with task 1, I am having trouble linking that to tasks 2 and 3.

For this example, I'll use the beaver1 and beaver2 data sets. This has two different groups (beaver 1 and beaver 2), a measurement we want to look at (temperature), and a variable to use as time (time).

```
beaver_data <-  bind_rows( 
  beaver1 %>% mutate(beaver = "1"),
  beaver2 %>% mutate(beaver = "2")
) %>%
  filter(!(beaver == "1" & day == 347)) %>% #Removing the 2nd day from each beaver for simplicity.
  filter(!(beaver == "2" & day == 308))

head(beaver_data)
# day time  temp activ beaver
# 1 346  840 36.33     0      1
# 2 346  850 36.34     0      1
# 3 346  900 36.35     0      1
# 4 346  910 36.42     0      1
# 5 346  920 36.55     0      1
# 6 346  930 36.69     0      1
```

Below, I have attached a somewhat simplified version of a nested loop that I'm using. As mentioned above, what it is doing is:

1. Creating a subset of the data with only data from that beaver, and measurements from within the past 100 seconds.
2. Checking if there is enough data to run the linear model.
3. Running the linear model.
4. Using the p value and slope to assign it to the data frame (which could be done with case_when()).

```
lim_little_data_trend <- 3  # The minimum number of rows to run a lm with
beaver_data$temp_trend <- NA # The variable that I want to define.

for(i in 1:nrow(beaver_data)){ # For each row
        
        beaver_data_trend_loop <- beaver_data %>%
          filter(beaver == beaver_data$beaver[i]) %>% #Only selecting rows from that beaver
          filter(between(time, beaver_data$time[i] - 100, beaver_data$time[i])) %>% #Selectng data from that moment and 100 seconds before
          drop_na(temp) # Dropping any NA values (an issue for my actual data set)
        
        if(nrow(beaver_data_trend_loop) < lim_little_data_trend){ #If there are not enough points, then classify as not enough data
          path_trend_loop <- "Not Enough Data"
        } else { #Otherwise, run a lm
          temp_trend_loop_lm <- lm(temp ~ time, data = beaver_data_trend_loop) #running the linear model
          
          temp_trend_loop_lm_sum <- summary(temp_trend_loop_lm) #storing the p value and slope
          
          if(is.na(temp_trend_loop_lm_sum$coefficients[2,4]) || temp_trend_loop_lm_sum$coefficients[2,4] > 0.1){ #If the p value is high, then assuming no trend. The first condition is for some extreme cases
            path_trend_loop <- "No Trend"
          } else if(temp_trend_loop_lm_sum$coefficients[2,1] > 0){ # If it is significant (defined as p < 0.1) and the slope is positive, then
            path_trend_loop <- "Increasing"
          } else { #If it is significant but has a negative trend, it is decreasing
            path_trend_loop <- "Decreasing"
          }
        }
        
        beaver_data$temp_trend[i] <- path_trend_loop # Assigning the trend to the original dataframe

}
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: How do you intend to deal with various time spans? Assuming a span of 100, looking at `beaver1[1,]` (`time=840`) there are 7 rows within 100 minutes (inclusive), but if we start at row 2 then we get a different set. Is this a "rolling window" or a "tumbling window"? Also, I'm assuming you're never going to go less than 100 (one hour); anything less and you'll run into problems with the fact that `beaver1$time` is (imho) a bad format, where `330` means `3:30`.

Comment: Good questions!

I think it's a rolling window (i.e. there is a lot of overlap in the data used from one row to the next). The next row may only have a few different points.

We will always stick with the same timeframe to look back.

Part of the reason we are only running the lm when there are at least 3 samples is because of situations like row 2. So we may run a lm at times < 100 sec after measurements began, but not when data are too scarce (e.g. just started or a data gap).

The real version uses dates. I chose these datasets because they have groups and (poorly formatted) time.

Comment: If you have `n` rows and if "enough data" means (say) 10 rows, then you can run up to `n-9` models, though it seems clear that some might not run due to larger gaps causing momentary data shortages. Does that seem right? Ultimately, what kind of regression results are you looking for?

Comment: That sounds right! And the only regression results that I need to keep are the slope and the p value for that slope. Those will then be used (maybe in case_when) to say whether we are seeing an increasing trend (for that beaver at that moment in time), a decreasing trend, or no trend.

Comment: Start with something like `lapply(seq_len(nrow(beavers)-5), function(rn) { dat <- filter(beavers[rn:nrow(beavers),], (time - first(time)) <= 100) ; if (nrow(dat) > 8) lm(..., data=dat); })`